# How to find out which machine keeps reading and deleting messages from an SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue and several machines that read from them. Although I have shut down all of them, somebody keeps reading and removing messages from the queue.

Is there any way to find the ip number of the machines that read messages from an SQS queue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot get the IP or EC2 instance that is performing these actions, but there are some steps you can take to attempt to narrow down what is consuming messages.

---

CloudTrail will only log the following actions to SQS:

- AddPermission
- CreateQueue
- DeleteQueue
- PurgeQueue
- RemovePermission
- SetQueueAttributes

This means that a consumer of the messages is not logged meaning CloudTrail cannot answer this question for you.

What you can do is use the IAM console to try and isolate which user or role is accessing the SQS service.  This will not narrow it down to which individual queue, but it is better than nothing.  You can look under the `Access Advisor` tab to check each user/role if it is using SQS.

If that is not enough to narrow down then you will probably have to resort to adding a policy to the SQS queue to start blocking users/roles from getting messages from that specific queue.  This will be a game of guess and check.  Alternatively, you could lock the queue down so only a specific user or role can read from the queue.

If you are using cross-account-access for this queue the above steps will not be as useful as you will not have the same level of visibility.  Also if you have the same role or user that is used by lots of different servers or applications this approach will also not work.  If that is the case this would be a good time to start applying least privilege as it can help with these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program in your message consumption application to run some of the queries here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html and then log for example the instance ID to somewhere you know you'll be able to pick it up.

This is redundant however if you don't know where to deploy this code (because you don't know the machine/group that is consuming the messages).

I could suggest manually creating a message in the SQS management console ( Queue Actions > Send a message), and create the message such that you know an error will be thrown by your consumer application (i.e. badly formatted or whatever). Then search the relevant location for the error- this will hopefully allow you to detect which machine threw it.